# Allow Moderator Comments with the Prefix "Moderator Note" to show up in collapsed comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools, moderators

[There was a question recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182233/should-a-very-good-and-constructive-answer-save-an-otherwise-not-constructive) that necessitated [a comment being put into the parent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699247/what-is-cache-friendly-code#comment24251475_16699247).

When I initally added the `Moderator Note` comment, there were 12 more comments there than there are now.  This meant that for someone visiting the post, they'd have to expand all comments, and find the important comment about the state of the post at the bottom.

I fixed it by deleting the meta-discussion comments, but I'd rather there be a better way.

This is also not the first time I've had to do this, it's just the first time I thought about a better way.

**Feature request**:  When a moderator leaves a comment on a post with the prefix **Moderator  Note:** in bold, the comment should appear even if the comments are collapsed, at the end of the collapsed comments (or at the beginning, but it'd be less weird if it appeared at the end).

Comment: I'd rather it appeared at the beginning. If a moderator leaves a moderator note, I'd say it's probably more important than any of the other comments there.

Comment: Related: [Allow moderator (and maybe 10k+ users) to pin comments so they are always displayed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131787/allow-moderator-and-maybe-10k-users-to-pin-comments-so-they-are-always-displa)

Comment: In red.  Definitely in red.

Comment: @Rory - With the <blink> tag.

Answer (score 29):

I would rather suggest a custom message in the form of a banner notice, like the one in a bounty message. That makes a visually prominent statement that a moderator has something important to tell every visitor to that question.

Compare the following messages:

[image: compare messages]

It would send a much clearer notice to visitors if a moderator can write a custom message in that banner. We can already do this when we place a bounty on questions, why not let the moderators write custom messages to posts that need special attention?

[image: custom notice]

Comment: This is a really good improvement on my feature request. +1.

Comment: If this were to be done, [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174864/a-special-kind-of-lock) needs needs to be fixed.  Right now the system will only display 2 banner messages, so if the moderator adds such a note, it will either been hidden by other banner messages or push out another message.  If this can't be fixed, I'd rather see a comment.

Comment: This was what I was just about to suggest; basically custom post notices just like lock/citation needed/etc

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think this works pretty well: The custom moderator notice would be a post notice (like Citation Needed), and the Lock would be the standard Locked notice *if applied* -- that's still only two  notices (and IMHO two is plenty - more than that and people will start ignoring them)

Comment: @voretaq7 You are right that more than 2 probably would get ignored, but my concern is that locked notices are already lower priority the "closed" and "migrated from", if you add in something else, which one gets pushed out.  I realize that all 4 on a single post would be rare, but posts that require a custom mod notice very well could have at least 1 other and may be 2.

Comment: @psubsee2003 True - perhaps the priorities should be shifted around a bit (Locked should certainly override Closed IMHO, and I'm of the opinion that Migrated From should just never be shown because it shouldn't matter...)