# This lock notice about collaborative effort is partly misleading

Tags: discussion, locked-questions, post-notices

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746692/restructuredtext-tool-support) is locked 
with the following notice:

> This question and answer are a collaborative effort: if you see something that can be improved, edit it!

Except that while the answer can be edited because it's a Community Wiki question, the question itself
 can't be, because it's locked. I don't know the reason why it was locked, but maybe the notice's text should
be changed or omitted? (I have no opinion on whether the question should stay locked or not.)

Comment: I believe the question is locked to forbid new answers being posted. This way you can *only* edit the CW answer.

Comment: Looks like it's fixed now: "This question's answer is a collaborative effort". Not misleading anymore. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am a bit confused. Which of the lock messages can be edited by mods? [I thought this wasn't possible at all.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182239/allow-moderator-comments-with-the-prefix-moderator-note-to-show-up-in-collapse/182240#182240)

Comment: It's not, @Antony. I edited it.

Comment: It's not an edited mod message; it's a potentially new feature that SE is experimenting with.  Handle with care; Alice may disappear into the rabbit hole without warning.

Comment: @Shog9 and Robert Presumably a feature in response to that very answer I linked?

Comment: No, it was already in work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've adjusted the wording slightly.

This is something the SO mods and I are experimenting a bit with right now. There are a small handful of questions that are not exactly appropriate for Stack Overflow, are popular and have useful answers where the primary value arises from the community's regular efforts to keep them updated via edits.

[Historical Locks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) are inappropriate for these, as they would then become ineligible for editing (thus destroying the one bit of value they bring to the site). The intent here is to emphasize the one valid use of Community Wiki:

> Community wiki is for that rare gem of a post that needs true community collaboration.
>
> *-[The Future of Community Wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)*

As I said, this is an experiment. We'll see how it works in practice.