# Allow accepting (self-)answers on historical-locked questions

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, self-answer, historical-lock

Assume a (self-answered) question gets locked for historical significance. Because of this, the user who posted the question cannot (repeat: not) perform any of these actions:

- mark own question as accepted.
- flag the question for moderator intervention.
- add comments to own question.
- delete own question (if that's what OPer would want to do).

OPer can only share it.

My suggestion: Provide an option to be able to mark OPer's own answer as accepted, by OPer (not via whatever moderator / SE employee intervention). So that the system does not block OPer from accepting OPer's own answer (after at least 2 days, as usual).

**Note**: This is a problem/issue that applies to any SE site, so it is not specific to a specific site. Try a similar scenario on any site, and you'll have the very same issue that the OPer cannot accept his/her own answer. Therefor I think this question belongs here, on Meta.SE.

Comment: I will say this. Historical significance is entirely the wrong lock reason for this. I don't know your history on that site and why a moderator took that action and cannot comment on that. I can only assume you know better than anyone else here why that may be.

Comment: @Oded there is a chance that mod intended [collaborativve effort lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182572/165773) (I briefly checked [the question on Drupal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/189569), can't tell for sure)

Comment: @gnat I'd be more inclined to think he locked it with historical significance to the Drupal community in mind, rather than the site itself

Comment: @Oded : please review my recent updates to this question. Even though your comment here about the specific question did make sense, I wonder if it still makes sense to continue to have your comment here. Apart from that, do you think it makes sense I would move the "my suggestion" part of it to a new (my own) answer, so that I can mark that as, IMO, the best possible solution/answer. If not, what kind of answer does it take for a feature request to be able for me to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 6):

The moderator seems to have left a [useful comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189569/how-to-proceed-with-a-d6-site-after-feb-24-2016-when-d6-is-end-of-life#comment229865_189569) that reads:

> As always, if you disagree with this, please bring it to Meta. But, know this was not a unilateral decision.

I strongly suspect they mean the site-specific meta so I  suggest you post an initial question about the decision on [Drupal's Meta](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/). If you aren't satisfied with the response there (or on any site-specific meta) you can either raise concerns about their response here or use the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of each page to raise your concerns with how it was handled with Stack Exchange staff.

Comment: you're right, I could do so, as that mod there also challenged me to do so. So +1 for this suggestion (I might refer to your answer here if I ever do that). But, I hope you agree that it is only like a work around for what my actual question really is about: "*how can I mark my own answer as accepted*" (shouldn't I have the right to do so, despite the current status this question/answer is in)? FYI, I think some kind of correction should be applied to SE sites, so that the system should not stop me from accepting my own answer (after at least 2 days, as usual).

Comment: "challenged"? I predict this will not go well for you. You need to understand why they locked it instead of deleting it. You need to understand why it's not a good fit for that site. Both are **far more important** than your preference that all your questions have an accepted answer. This site can't give you that insight, but the Drupal meta site can.

Comment: If you continue to delete questions because they are locked, you will quickly find yourself, without the ability to post questions.