# Reputation needed to edit Q&As with Wiki Answer lock?

Tags: support, community-wiki, locked-questions

I think [Wiki Answer locks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182572/215590) can be usefully applied to questions that have attracted a list of answers, and become popular, before anyone realized their poor fit to focussed Q&A.

This is where they can be set by Moderators.

[image]

However, I struggle to find any detailed description of them.

On GIS SE Meta a question has been asked about who can edit Q&As which have a Wiki Answer lock ([Who can edit locked CW posts?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4595)) and I am not certain of my answer to it.

For a Q&A with a Wiki Answer lock:

- Can anyone besides Moderators edit the question?
- Can all of the existing answers be edited by users with the [edit community wiki privilege](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) at 100?

Comment: Lock is a lock. Pretty sure it doesn't matter what is the notice attached to it. So only moderators can edit it, same as with any locked post.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think [this (from Animuson)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182566/this-lock-notice-is-partly-misleading#comment556277_182566) suggests otherwise.

Comment: @ShadowWizard and [this (from Shog9)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182566/this-lock-notice-is-partly-misleading/182572#182572) too

Comment: Guess it means the lock can be applied only to the question, while not affecting the answers themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you lock a post, you're literally just locking the post. That means the actual post with the lock cannot be edited, cannot be voted on, cannot have anything done to it. The reason is actually just a post notice that gets submitted along with the action. The only post notice that interacts with the lock to change the way the question and its answers appear is the historical lock. All others are just text in a box alongside a post lock.

So the community wiki answer reason effectively blocks all users from editing the question directly. It does absolutely nothing to its answers, and does not inherently change the reputation requirement to edit its answers. This lock reason is often coupled with converting the question (and thus its answers too) to a community wiki to lower the bar for editing its answers. Without completing that action too, full editing privileges will still be required.

Comment: "The only post notice that interacts with the lock to change the way the question and its answers appear is the historical lock. All others are just text in a box alongside a post lock." - The comment-only lock (which was added since this post was made) interacts with the post in a unique way as well, right? I believe it prevents commenting, without affecting other interactions with the "locked" post (votes, edits, etc.).

Comment: @V2Blast Yes. The comment lock wasn't added after this post (it is present in the screenshot above), just reworked and special-cased to not lock out other stuff. But that lock still doesn't change the overall appearance of the post either (whereas the historical lock removes voting buttons and other things completely).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was specifically referring to [the ability to lock only the comments of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340198/335251), without preventing voting/edits/etc.