# Remove "Wiki Answer" lock option on answers because it's misleading

Tags: feature-request, status-review, moderator-tools, locked, locked-answers

Currently, moderators can put a "Wiki Answer" lock on *both questions and answers*. Its description is:

> Lock this post to encourage users to edit existing answers. Remember to remove unnecessary answers and to mark questions and their answers as Community Wiki posts.

Also, an answer by staff regarding the lock on [Reputation needed to edit Q&As with Wiki Answer lock?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296710/241919) mentioned:

> When you lock a post, you're literally just locking the post. That means the actual post with the lock cannot be edited, cannot be voted on, cannot have anything done to it. [...]
>
> So the community wiki answer reason effectively blocks all users from editing the question directly. It does absolutely nothing to its answers, [...]

Thus, when the lock is (accidentally) applied to answers, *they cannot be edited anymore*, contradicting the post notice.

Please remove the "Wiki Answer" lock option on answers because it is misleading, and also because moderators aren't affected by the lock, so they may not realize the restriction.

Comment: There was at one point the ability to [lock answers for historical significance](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7922/historical-significance-lock-reason-on-answers-still-states-this-question). The notice would incorrectly display a notice for questions, though, and this option was later removed (even if there are [cases where it's useful](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1208/56425)).