# Link a post on the main site to its meta post

Tags: discussion, api

Can you add a link to "share edit flag" such that you would have "share edit flag meta" which would either link you to the meta for this specific question or create a meta question associated with this question?

IMHO, it would cut down on the discussion in comments on some questions - such as those commonly found in Christianity.SE.

Comment: Leaving a simple comment with a link to the meta post doesn't work? Do you have an example?

Comment: Are you proposing that instead of a comment with the link from some user, possibly in a pool of other comments, that the link is featured in some way, perhaps at the top of all the comments, like the notice about sources on answers? Because I could support that. Either way, I'm having trouble understanding your post.

Comment: @fredsbend if [moderators could pin comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242319/162102), this would be doable without any extra work.  (Well ok, you have to ask a mod to pin it after you add the comment, but I mean no extra development work.)

Comment: @fredsbend I was attempting to keep the comments to a min. by having a consistent link to a meta question for a question.  Monica is right, if a mod could pin a comment, it would also be a good solution.  I feel that sometimes the comments in questions are important.  HOWEVER it is the mod's responsibility to remove unneeded discussion - which is on par for a meta or chat.

Answer (score 12):

Create the question and then comment with the link.  Or if you notice a case where this didn't happen, go ahead and add the comment.

Questions with associated meta discussions should be pretty rare as a proportion of overall question count, so most of the time this would be noise.  You could say that flags and closures are also rare, but those situations are more serious and there's no other alternative to accomplish those tasks; here, there's an easy work-around, the comment.  Finally, adding stuff to the UI increases complexity, both in user experience and in implementation.  This doesn't seem to pass a cost-benefit analysis.

Comment: "cost-benefit analysis"? Do you have some inside track on SE's expenditures and revenues? The rest of your answer seems fine. That part just seems weird.

Comment: @fredsbend I don't mean dollars; I mean the things I enumerated: load on the users, complexity (both code and UI), irrelevance the vast majority of the time.  All that versus saving a couple clicks and typing/selecting a comment on the rare occasions when it's needed.

Comment: @fredsbend Not to mention, you don't really have to have inside knowledge of Stack Exchange accounting to know that a feature costs designer, developer, tester, and probably a few other positions' time, which translates to money. They do a lot of cool features for us, but they do have to weigh pros and cons of each one and prioritize, just like any other service provider. That would be true whether they were making no money, or several million dollars a year. Every feature is an investment, and Monica's point was that this doesn't seem like a worth-while one right now.